# Android Picasso 2.5.2, showing images from adapter inside listivew. With async task

Tags: android, listview, adapter, picasso

I would like to use `Picasso` library to download and show images that are in URL's inside `JSON` data from my server.

I've lost all hope, I saw something about `custom adapter` but to no avail.
I need help here.

Here's how I do stuff now to show data from `json` inside `onPostExecute`:

```
protected  void onPostExecute(JSONObject objdanejson){
    pDialog.dismiss();

    try {
        android = objdanejson.getJSONArray(TAG_ZAWARTOSC);
        for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

            final String akt_tytul = c.getString(TAG_TYTUL);
            final String akt_skrot = c.getString(TAG_SKROT);
            final String akt_tresc = c.getString(TAG_TRESC);
            final String akt_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            final String akt_IMG = c.getString(TAG_IMG);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_TYTUL, akt_tytul);
            map.put(TAG_SKROT, akt_skrot);
            map.put(TAG_ID, akt_id);
            map.put(TAG_TRESC, akt_tresc);
            map.put("http://www.apirest.poligon.webimpuls.pl/"+TAG_IMG, akt_IMG);

            oslist.add(map);
            lista_aktualnosci = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_aktualnosci);

            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(aktualnosci.this, oslist,
                R.layout.aktualnosc_item,
                new String[]{TAG_TYTUL, TAG_SKROT, TAG_IMG}, new int[]{R.id.aktTytul, R.id.aktSkrot, R.id.aktIMG});

            lista_aktualnosci.setAdapter(adapter);

            lista_aktualnosci.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(aktualnosci.this, "Kliknąłeś na " + oslist.get(+position).get("akt_tytul"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent czytaj = new Intent(aktualnosci.this, aktualnosc_czytaj.class);
                    czytaj.putExtra("tytuł",oslist.get(+position).get("akt_tytul"));
                    czytaj.putExtra("tresc",oslist.get(+position).get("akt_tresc"));
                    czytaj.putExtra("id",oslist.get(+position).get("akt_id"));
                    startActivity(czytaj);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

How my custom controler looks:

```
oslist.add(map);
lista_aktualnosci = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_aktualnosci);

/*   final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(aktualnosci.this, oslist,
    R.layout.aktualnosc_item,
    new String[]{TAG_TYTUL, TAG_SKROT}, new int[]{R.id.aktTytul, R.id.aktSkrot});
*/
class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClipData.Item> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ClipData.Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.aktualnosc_item, null);
        }

        ClipData.Item p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            aktTytul = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.aktTytul);
            aktSkrot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.aktSkrot);
            aktIMG = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aktIMG);
        }

        return v;
    }

}

lista_aktualnosci.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you need to implement a custom adapter...show your custom adapter code and then we can check it..also, save your data in a model class and pass that entire object to your custom adapter

Comment: Instead of Async task you can use retrofit..it will automatically set the json result into your model class.

Comment: I have no idea how to start creating custom adapter. With this I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends `Simple Adapter` or `Base Adapter`. In `getView()` the `adapter` will ask you to create a list item when this is needed. As you create the item you can use Picasso to display the image in whatever image view you've selected for this purpose.

That being said you should ditch `ListView` and use `RecyclerView` instead - for which you can find all the information you need [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)

Other stuff that may improve your code are things like `Retrofit` and `Gson`.

Does that help?

Comment: So how exacly that class should look like?

Comment: I did something, but IDK how it relate to mine code.

Comment: To be hones after looking at what you posted Picasso is the least of your problems. You should really go back to basics and look into how inheritance works and how android handles views and lists of views. The only other way someone could help you right now would be to write your code for you.

Comment: I just need a little hint of code. Then I will get it.

Comment: No, you need to go back and study the basics of object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your image from listview. You can this code your activity after set adapter then you can set your imageview.

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.listView.getChildCount(); i ++) {
           View view = this.listView.getChildAt(i);
           ImageView img= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourimage);
           //do something your image 
}
```

Comment: You can call your image with picasso